# LESS doesn't work

Tags: html, css, rendering, less

I can't get less-1.5.1.min.js to work... Here is the files I tried:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="js/less-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/config.less" />
```

**LESS**

```
@black:     #000000;
@white:     #ffffff;
```

and **CSS**

```
header {
    background: @black;
}
```

I have uploaded the files to the server. You can see for yourself here: http://www.battlefield4forum.pl/messenger

Can someone tell me why it doesn't work? I have no idea why...

**

## EDIT:

**

Thanks :)

Now it looks like this:

**site.less**

```
@black:         #000000;
@white:         #ffffff;

header {
    background: @black;

    h2 {
        color: @white;
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!-- Loading LESS -->
<script src="js/less-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/config.less" />

<!-- Loading CSS -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And now I don't have the file *style.css*. Do I understand you correctly?

You can still see it here: http://www.battlefield4forum.pl/messenger

Comment: The `header` tag is invisible, so adding a color to its background won't change anything. ;) Try `body{background-color: @black;}`

Comment: Your `@black` isn't being evaluated it's showing as @black in the CSS and you're also not setting anything. You need to set `background-color` not background.

Answer (score 1):

The variables declared in your config.less will only be available within the scope of that file. The styles you have defined in css/styles.css won't be able to see these variables at all since they are...

A) loaded before your less file and

B) aren't considered less and so won't be picked up by your client-side less processing

To fix, **move the styles in your css/styles.css file into your config.less file**. You might also consider naming it something like site.less.

Answer (score 0):

if it is still not working, try to move your less styles before js compiler:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/config.less" />
<script src="js/less-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```